# not understanding this javascript equation

Tags: javascript

Em. I'm looking at the easing equation here:

```
var easing = function( t, b, c, d ) {
   return c * ( t /= d ) * t * t * t + b;
}
```

So presumably one can write it like this:

```
var easing = function( t, b, c, d ) {
   return c * ( t = (t/d) ) * t * t * t + b;
}
```

or like this ?  mmm.. not sure about this one:

```
var easing = function( t, b, c, d ) {
   return c * t = c * (t/d) * t * t * t + b;
}
```

How exactly is this equation being parsed by javascript, I mean, we get:

return number = number;

wtf? How is this being handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that expression are evaluated from left to right, the expression can be simplified by following steps:

1)

```
var easing = function( t, b, c, d ) {
   return c * ( t = (t/d) ) * t * t * t + b;
}
```

2)

```
var easing = function( t, b, c, d ) {
   t = t/d;
   return c * t * t * t * t + b;
}
```

3)

```
var easing = function( t, b, c, d ) {
   return c * Math.pow(t/d, 4) + b;
}
```

JsFiddle for the code: http://jsfiddle.net/caGWz/

Comment: omg. I just had an incredible brain fart. lol:) well of course it is.

Comment: I thought /= has the lowest precedence and would therefore be evaluated last. What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1):

When an assignment expression appears in a larger expression, it evaluates to the value of the right-side operand.  So in this case, the sub-expression `( t /= d )` takes on the value `( t / d )` in the overall expression.  Also, since `( t /= d )` is the left-most sub-expression in parentheses, it is evaluated first (due to the standard PEMDAS order of operations), so `t` takes on the value `( t / d )` for the rest of the expression.

Comment: sure. You know  I definitely knew about this. I just had an incredible brain fart there.